# Multiple Java IF statement writing a JSON response to Excel using Apache Poi XSSF

Tags: java, json, if-statement, testng, rest-assured

I have a test that returns a JSON response some if the responses might return nulls depending on the tests for example the response path will look like

data.test1[0]

data.test1[1]

data.test1[2]

data.test2[0]

data.test2[0]

data.test2[0]

The response that is returned is very big and almost 400 lines worth of data.test

So what I have done is a basic if to check if the response is not null then wright to excel. This is working but it made the tests extremely slow.

If statement that works :

```
if(response.path("data.test1[0]" )!= null){    
XSSFCell dataTest1 = rowResults.createCell(1);
   dataTest1.setCellValue(response.path("data.test1[0]").toString());
}
```

```
if(response.path("data.test1[1]" )!= null){    
XSSFCell dataTest2 = rowResults.createCell(2);
  dataTest1.setCellValue(response.path("data.test1[1]").toString());
}
```

I created this if multiple times for each response data. But like I said this has made it very slow I even tried change to SXSSF Apache POI but did not make a difference.

I have also tried bundling the IF statement but then I get null pointer exception I tried the below

```
if(response.path("data.test1" )!= null){    
XSSFCell dataTest1 = rowResults.createCell(1);
 dataTest1.setCellValue(response.path("data.test1[0]").toString());

XSSFCell dataTest2 = rowResults.createCell(2); 
dataTest1.setCellValue(response.path("data.test1[1]").toString());
}
```

Do you have any suggestion to check if a JSON response is null but on an array I am not sure what the best is but any advise or suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you show your json with mentioning what to put to spreadsheet and what not? Also did you analyze which part exactly consumes the time?

Answer (score 0):

If you know how many array elements you got back, like for example `data.test1[0]`, `data.test1[1]` and `data.test1[2]`, you can use a loop to do something for all the indexes like this:

```java
for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
    if(response.path("data.test1["+Integer.toString(i)+"]")!= null){
        rowResults.createCell(i+1).setCellValue(response.path("data.test1["+Integer.toString(i)+"]").toString());
   }
}
```

And if you know how many suffixes are after `test` like `data.test1[0]`, `data.test1[1]`, `data.test1[2]`, `data.test2[0]`, ..., you can use nested loops like this:

```java
int count = 1;
for (int i = 1; i <= 2; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
        if (response.path("data.test"+Integer.toString(i)+"[" + Integer.toString(j) + "]") != null) {
            rowResults.createCell(count++).setCellValue(response.path("data.test"+Integer.toString(i)+"[" + Integer.toString(j) + "]").toString());
        }
    }
}
```